# Margins are not working?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a div, "top" inside of "theform", which I want to be centered and 2em for top-margin. It gets centered but is not 2em for top-margin. And -webkit-box-align: center; is not working either because I need "mainphoto" centered.

Any ideas? Possibly margin collapsing? I couldn't find a fix for it if it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/D2BC4/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <body>
        <?php
        ?>
        <div id="theform">
            <form>
                <div id="top">
                    <div id="mainphoto">

                    </div>
                    <div id="title">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{  
    font-size:100%;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
} 

body{
    width: 100%;
}

#mainphoto{
    display:-webkit-box;
    width:22em;
    height:17em;
    border:1px solid red;
}


#theform{
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    width: 55em;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px black solid;
}

#title{
    display:-webkit-box;
}

#top{
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 50em;
    height:20em;
    overflow:auto;
    border:2px red solid;
}



#wrapper{
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-border-radius:0.9em;
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 5px #888888;
    margin: 3em auto;
    width: 80em;
    height:52em;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you never use the 2009 Flexbox properties without also providing properties from the standard spec:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/.  You never know when browsers will drop support for properties from that old draft.

Comment: @cimmanon thanks but do you know the answer to my problem too?

Comment: What you're looking to achieve is unclear.  Center which way?  Horizontal?  Vertical?  You have lots of elements that have been turned into *flex containers* for no reason.  You're using properties that only work on flex containers on elements that aren't flex containers.  You have a `div` containing your `body` tag, which is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

add margin to your `#mainphoto` to make it center

```
#mainphoto{
    display:-webkit-box;
    width:22em;
    height:17em;
    margin:2em auto 0 auto;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2BC4/3/)

hope this help

Comment: I want it aligned with box-align. And not centered. I want the div "top" to be centered and have a top margin of 2em

Comment: you main `#top` should be `center`, `#mainphoto` should be in left corner of `#top` can you show me image, of what you want to achieve if ok with you.